# Get every 30 mins interval of 24 hrs in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

May I ask if you guys have an idea on how to achieve the table below in ms sql:

Time interval is every 30 mins depends on the date range that will be given as parameter.

Ex. Date Range = 02/02/2015 - 02/03/2015

[image]

Comment: exists the data in the table or not? what is the question?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a date table with entries for every 30 minutes?

Comment: Hi! The table does not exist. I'm asking how to create this table or at least to say the data that will be input to the table.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a numbers table then use that to generate the 30 minute intervals to be added to the start date.

```
declare @fromDate datetime; set @fromDate = '2015-02-02'
declare @toDate datetime; set @toDate = '2015-02-03'

; with cteNumbers as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by o1.object_id, o2.object_id) - 1 as rn
    from
        sys.objects o1
            cross join sys.objects o2
)
select
    dateadd(minute, rn * 30, @fromDate) as DateTimeInterval
from
    cteNumbers
where 
    dateadd(minute, rn * 30, @fromDate) between @fromDate and @toDate
order by 
    DateTimeInterval
```

Answer (score 2):

This will populate a table as you've asked.
As you can see it simply populates a table with the date held in the variable, adds 30 minutes to the variable, loops around, checks if it is more than the end date and starts over again or exits.

```
Declare @dateFrom date,
        @dateTo date,
        @currentDate datetime
Declare @Dates table (date varchar(30))

    Set @dateFrom = '2015-01-01'
    Set @dateTo = '2015-01-02'

    Set @currentDate = Cast(@dateFrom as datetime) + '00:00:00'

While @currentDate < @dateTo
Begin

Insert into @Dates values (Convert(varchar, @currentDate, 120) + ' - ' + Convert(varchar, DATEADD(Mi, 30, @currentDate),108)) 

Set @currentDate = DATEADD(Mi, 30, @currentDate)

end

Select * from @Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round down a Datetime value to every half hour using the following formula:

```
cast(cast(cast(MyDateTimeValue as numeric(38,18)) * 48 as int) / 48.0 as datetime)
```

This way for example, 02/03/2015 01:37 AM becomes 02/03/2015 01:30 AM

Answer (score 0):

To create the desired date range you can write as:

```
DECLARE @s DATEtime = '20150202', @e DATEtime = '20150203';    

;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT  TOP ((DATEDIFF(HOUR , @s, @e)*2)+1)
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) AS rownum,
 DATEADD(minute, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) -1)*30, @s) AS dt
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' 
 )
 SELECT T1.dt AS StartRange,
        T2.dt AS EndRange 
 FROM CTE AS T1
 JOIN CTE AS T2 ON T1.rownum + 1 = T2.rownum
```